# Inno setup search for existing file

Tags: inno-setup

How can I search for an existing exe file and then use that directory for my installer ?

If the exe file is not found I would like the user to browse for the path. In case the exe file is installed somewhere else.

***Senario 1 (most common cases):***

Default dir is c:\test\My program

This should be shown as the path on the "Select Destination Location" page
When the user press Next, there should be a check. To make sure that the default dir exist (c:\test\My program)
If it exist, the user should just continue to the Ready to Install page.

***Senario 2 (very seldom cases):***

Default dir is c:\test\My program

This should be shown as the path on the "Select Destination Location" page
When the user press Next, there should be a check. To make sure that the default dir exist (c:\test\My program)
If it does not exist, the user should be prompt for the path to "My program". The user should afterwards continue to the Ready to Install page.
I then just trust that the user selects the correct path

How can I do this in InnoSetup ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to look for the path where your application was previously installed ? If so, then it's done *"by default"*. Or do you want to have e.g. a custom page with a directory edit box prefilled by the searched directory ?

Comment: I mean: I have an Test application default installed to c:\program files\picture\picture.exe My Inno installer should then search for that path and copy 2-3 files to that dir. But if a customer has installed the test application somewhere else, I need Inno to search for picture.exe. If picture.exe is not found in the default directory the customer should just be told to browse for it. So Inno setup will copy the 2-3 files to the correct directory. Maybe there is a better way to do this. But there is no Registry string I can search for. I think your suggestion with a custom page sounds good

Comment: You should not search for a file but rather look in the registry or similar to find its real location, or check a few specific locations. Search a hard disk with many GB of data and millions of files will take forever.

Comment: How was the "existing application already installed" installed in the first place? If it was installed via Inno-Setup and had a unique `AppName`/`AppId` you wouldn't have this problem updating your existing application - your update program would have had `{app}` variable automatically point to `c:\program files\picture` (or wherever it was initially installed to).

Comment: To answer the question asked you might want to look at: [Scan a disk path or an entire disk with Inno Setup - Example script](http://www.dateiliste.com/de/quellkode/17-inno-setup/94-scan-a-disk-path-or-an-entire-disk-with-inno-setup.html?start=3). Just a warning: Note that `picture.exe` could belong to *another* application, And you should have other means to 100% recognize it as yours (md5/version/etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a file input page and let user choose the `Picture.exe` binary location manually, when it won't be found on expected location.

You can follow the [**commented version**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14841853/1) of this code:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: "CurrentBinary.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "PictureExtension.dll"; DestDir: "{code:GetDirPath}"

[Code]
var
  FilePage: TInputFileWizardPage;

function GetDirPath(const Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := '';
  if FileExists(FilePage.Values[0]) then
    Result := ExtractFilePath(FilePage.Values[0]);
end;         

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  FilePath: string;
begin
  FilePage := CreateInputFilePage(wpSelectDir, 'Select Picture.exe location', 
    'Where is Picture.exe installed ?', 'Select where Picture.exe is located, ' +
    'then click Next.');
  FilePage.Add('Location of Picture.exe:', 'Picture project executable|Picture.exe', 
    '.exe');

  FilePage.Edits[0].ReadOnly := True;
  FilePage.Edits[0].Color := clBtnFace;

  FilePath := ExpandConstant('{pf}\Picture\Picture.exe');
  if FileExists(FilePath) then
    FilePage.Values[0] := FilePath;
end;
```

Comment: I'am missing "CurrentBinary.exe" and "PictureExtension.dll"

Comment: Me too; they are just fictive :-) Replace those file names with your real file names. I wanted to show how to distinguish between file entries and destinations where will be installed. Entries like `CurrentBinary.exe` will be installed to the target directory and entries like `PictureExtension.dll` will be installed to the chosen `Picture.exe` directory.

Comment: Ahh of course. I'll test this tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: This is almost perfect. But is there a way to only show the file input page if the exe file is not found. Now it is shown every time regardless if the exe file is found or not. If the exe was found - the installer should just use that dir and not prompt user when pressing "next"

Comment: You can put in a ShouldSkipPage rule to skip the page if the executable was found in the chosen path.  But be careful -- if you do this the easy way then you can produce an odd user experience.  For example, the path may not have been found automatically, so the user selects the path manually, clicks Next, then realises that they wanted to choose a different location and clicks Back -- but they can no longer get to the page to change it.  There are ways to resolve this but it's far simpler just to leave the page showing as normal, just in case the path you found isn't the one the user wants.

Comment: @Miral, there's also the case e.g. when the file is not found and the user will just ignore that selection and continue. This needs to be clarified...

Comment: If the Picture.exe is not found in the default installdir, the user should be prompt to "browse" for the file or dir. It should not be possible to continue if the Picture.exe does not exist

Comment: No problem, just (precisely) describe how, and I'll include it into the script.

Comment: @TLama, I have sent a mail to you with a description

Comment: Ok, will check the mailbox. But don't you rather edit your question and include it here ?

Comment: I used mail because the description was too long :o( Tried to descripe it as precisely as I could

Comment: Sorry for being too late. I was going to modify my answer to fit the question. You might not accept it so early. I'm just having InnoSetup holiday these days, so if you'll be patient, I'll post the script you need :-)

Comment: @TLama, I used your first example and modified it a bit. With the help from the link from Kobik. Thanks to all for very useful inputs..

Comment: @TLama , please when user just click Next without selecting any file/folder it will install to the C: folder, how can i add a condition to only accept Next when the input is properly selected?

Answer (score 5):

I do a similar thing with my installer already. The first thing I do is need to read the registry value from the program, and if that registry value is absent then I select that program's default directory. For example:

```
DefaultDirName={reg:HKLM\Software\Activision\Battlezone II,STInstallDir|reg:HKLM\Software\Activision\Battlezone II,Install121Dir|{pf32}\Battlezone II}
```

Now, the user runs the installer, and it has to check if the program is in the right folder. It does so by checking that the program's executable file already exists. I use this piece of code to do so.

```
{ Below code warns end user if he tries to install into a folder that does not contain bzone.exe. Useful if user tries to install into addon or any non-BZ2 folder. }
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Log('NextButtonClick(' + IntToStr(CurPageID) + ') called');
  case CurPageID of
    wpSelectDir:
    if not FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\bzone.exe')) then begin
      MsgBox('Setup has detected that that this is not the main program folder of a Battlezone II install, and the created shortcuts to launch {#MyAppName} will not work.' #13#13 'You should probably go back and browse for a valid Battlezone II folder (and not any subfolders like addon).', mbError, MB_OK);
      end;
    wpReady:
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

The above code simply checks that the target executable exists and warns the user if it does not, giving him the chance to go back and change directories but also to go ahead with the install anyways.

Also, as you appear to be installing a patch or addon to an existing program, I recommend you set

```
DirExistsWarning=no
AppendDefaultDirName=false
```

And optionally to prevent an unnecessary screen if you are not creating start menu entries

```
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
```