# Inno Setup, How to search specific string in several files?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to search specific string in several files.
e.g. `oem1.inf` `oem2.inf` `oem5.inf` `oem8.inf`...
All the target file names have the same format - `oem*.inf`
I want to search specific substring (e.g. `"1234"` in `"ABA1234"`) in these files.
I have referenced [Inno setup search for existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839677/inno-setup-search-for-existing-file), but it's a little different from my question.

---

I could get all path now:

```pascal
Var
  FilesFound: Integer;
  FindRec: TFindRec;
  Stemp: String;
begin
  FilesFound := 0;
  if FindFirst('C:\Path\oem*.inf', FindRec) then begin
    try
      repeat
        if FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0 then
        begin
          temp := 'C:\Path\' + FindRec.Name;
          MsgBox(temp, mbInformation, MB_OK);
          FilesFound := FilesFound + 1;
        end;
      until not FindNext(FindRec);
    finally
      FindClose(FindRec);
    end;
  end;
  MsgBox(IntToStr(FilesFound) + ' files found in the System directory.',
    mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

---

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I could use "FileExists" to check the file, but i don't know which .inf is the last one, maybe oem35.inf or oem99.inf ? I need a method to get all the oem*.inf path or stop searching at the last one.
The specific text part, I don't have any idea. Maybe someone could provide some advices. Thanks

Comment: You don't need `FileExists`. The code you've already posted tells you that a file matching `ome*.inf` was found, and when you've reached the last one then the `not FindNext(findRec)` will exit the loop.

Comment: I post code below, thanks Martin and Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this question. Thanks Martin and Ken.

```pascal
Var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
  I: Integer;
  Tag: String;
  Line: String;
  FileLines: TStringList;
begin
  if FindFirst('C:\PATH\oem*.inf', FindRec) then
    begin
      try
        FileLines := TStringList.Create;
        Tag := 'ABA1234';
        repeat
          if FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0 then
            begin
              FileLines.LoadFromFile('C:\PATH\' + FindRec.Name);
              for I := 0 to FileLines.Count - 1 do
                begin
                  Line := FileLines[I];
                  if (Pos(Tag, Line) > 0) then
                    MsgBox(temp, mbInformation, MB_OK);
                end;
            end;
        until not FindNext(FindRec);
      finally
        FileLines.Free;
        FindClose(FindRec);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: You can replace whole `for` loop with `if (Pos(Tag, FileLines.Text) > 0) then { found }`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thanks, I have another question([HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017688/inno-setup-how-to-pass-parameter-from-code-to-uninstallrun)), could you please take a look?